# Serializing a generic field with jaxb using XMLAdapter

Tags: java, xml, generics, jaxb

We have a class which defines an object ID (UID):

public final class UUID implements Serializable, Comparable {
....
}

and another class:

```
    @XmlType(name = "ChangeFieldValueInstruction")
    public static class ChangeFieldValueInstruction<T> extends Instruction
    {
        private T newVal;

        public ChangeFieldValueInstruction()
        {
            super();
        }

        public ChangeFieldValueInstruction(String fieldPath, T newVal)
        {
            super(fieldPath);
            setNewVal(newVal);
        }


        public T getNewVal()
        {
            return newVal;
        }

        public void setNewVal(T newVal)
        {
            this.newVal = newVal;
        }
      ................
    }
```

This class (UpdateObjectRequest) is passed through a web service (we use spring).

I have a package-info file which defines an adapter for UUID.class, but when when we pass to newVal a UID object, we see that that adapter is not called and in fact the default UID constructor is called.
I tried annotating the getNewVal() method with @XmlAnyElement, and adding @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to the UID class as well (as someone advised here) but still it does not work. also tried annotating UpdateObjectRequest with @XmlSeeAlso(UUID.class)
BTW in the xsd i see that newVal is defined as xs:anyType

So does anyone know how can i get this to work? 10x.

Comment: Have a look at this http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html I think `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, imho.

How is this supposed to work? You would have a dynamic XML schema of your SOAP WebService payload.
How should the receiving service react, he can't guess the type of the element.

Using SOAP, the webservice and its operations, XML types are pre-defined in the WSDL - WebService Definition.
This is how client and server can interoperate, because they negotiated on a payload format, which is not dynamic.

You need to exactly define, which messages, types may be passed between ws client and server

Comment: yeah it make sense, but, it does work for other types such as String, int etc... so you think it's impossible? maybe we can workaround it somehow?

Comment: use concrete classes for transmission.

Comment: can you explain..? We need that newVal to be generic (or object - which i understood is the same) because it can be of any type..

Comment: You could define your own type hierarchy of "NewValue" classes, instead of generics. If you rely on Object in your JAXB class, you could write a XmlAdapter, that transforms between Object classes and "NewValue" classes, known by JAXB. Im sure you don't want to transfer every "Object" through the service. Find and define which objects are transfered. Maybe you need to use Data Transfer Objects.